# What is the difference between net.ltgt.gwt.maven and org.codehaus.mojo GWT Maven plugins?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

Apparently, there are two maven plugins for GWT:

This one:

```
<groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-rc-6</version>
```

and this one:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

What are the differences ?

Comment: They're just two different plugins by different vendors. Both projects seem active at the time of writing. The discussion on whether one is better than the other doesn't really pertain to SO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm a former maintainer of the `org.codehaus.mojo` plugin, and author of the `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` one.*

The plugins have very different approaches to using GWT with Maven; I'll try to summarize the most important ones here.

First, the `org.codehaus.mojo` is tied to a specific version of GWT; this means a new version of the plugin has to be released whenever a new version of GWT is released to account for differences. On the other hand, it exposes all GWT options/flags right as configuration properties, with Maven documentation (`mvn gwt:help`) et al. When a bug is fixed in the plugin, this also means you have to update your GWT version to match the one used by the next plugin release; while you really should always use the latest GWT version, it might not be possible to update quickly due to other dependencies being incompatible with the new version, etc. so you may be in "version conflict hell".
The `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` plugin aims at being compatible with the 2 latest versions of GWT, but is likely compatible with many more (it's just not tested / guaranteed); this means that you can update the plugin independently of GWT.
The `org.codehaus.mojo` plugin brings the `gwt-dev` and `gwt-user` (and `gwt-servlet`!) dependencies, which can cause conflicts with those from the project's dependencies if not strictly identical; also, due to how Maven works, you cannot exclude them from the plugin's dependencies if you use your own forked version of GWT under a different `groupId` (you'd have to either use the `com.google.gwt` `groupId`, or fork the plugin to change its dependenceis).

The `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` plugin comes with custom `packaging`s for `gwt-lib` and `gwt-app`. It's quite opinionated on how GWT apps should be done with Maven: separating client and server (and shared) code into separate Maven modules (this is actually following The Maven Way™: if you need separate classpaths, then you need to use different Maven modules, each with their dependencies). You're of course not forced to use those packagings, they just cut quite a bit of configuration in the POMs by setting appropriate defaults and conventions.

Finally, because of that above-stated opinionated view on "project layout", the `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` plugin is designed to support multi-module (aka reactor) builds, contrary to the `org.codehaus.mojo` plugin where, for instance, `gwt:run` has to be run on a project where both client and server code "live"; leading to awful hacks in multi-module builds like having to `mvn install` all dependency modules (because `gwt:run` cannot be invoked on the aggregator module) and using the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to bring in client sources from the other modules for seamless development experience.

You can see the differences between the plugins in [this commit](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/commit/b3ef2b90f3435323c9aef0a0ba93677a98b0e5b9) on the gwt-maven-archetypes (*disclaimer: I'm the author*) which switched from the `org.codehaus.mojo` to the `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I am glad I got a response from a person involved in both projects. The second one seems like what I need.

Comment: The problem with my answer is that it's obviously opinionated and subjective ;-)

Comment: Oh, BTW, we switched all samples in GWT proper from `org.codehaus.mojo` to `net.ltgt.gwt.maven` too: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/a0de97b999468b12d6c19d6a470ca03b2a2b4557%5E%21/ (**not** using the `gwt-app` packaging)

Comment: Sounds great this multi-module approach. Is there an example project with GWT and Google App Engine (in this  multi-module maven style)?